# Print with GDI+ has no effect

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi+

I added GDI+ to my Win32 Application for drawing gradients quite a while ago. I worked around some problems considering mixed GDI and GDI+ output and everything works fine.

Now i started to use GDI+ also for printing, but all calls to GDI+ seem to be ignored, that work fine on screen. I double checked that there is no clipping region. Also the coordinates are on paper. I also eliminated all GDI output for testing. Still a blank page is shown. I tried several printers. A test with the [GDI+ printing samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533891%28VS.85%29.aspx) works without problems. I added the code used in my application to the sample, and it also works without problems.

Any idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I recently had a similar problem - creating a Graphics object from a DC applied a scaling factor that wasn't obvious, and my stuff was all rendering off the page. Fixing it was a simple one-liner:

```
graphics.SetPageUnit(UnitPixel);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Isn't it unbelievable?

Comment: Brilliant! Solved my problem. My GDI+ bevels were printing OK, but DrawImage was not showing up. SetPageUnit fixed it. Although the image thumbnails were showing full sized. Had to use DrawImage(Image *, x, y, w, h) to make it fit. Thanks, wish I could give you more points.

Comment: Why doesn't the @#$% Microsoft example include this little tidbit? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533891%28VS.85%29.aspx